# Chabad Tallis vs Chabad Munkatch

Tags: chabad, tallit-gadol, chassidic-rebbe

Hey recently while shopping for a new Chabad Tallis I found a distinction between the normal Chabad Tallis, the Rashab Chabad Tallis, and the Munkatch Chabad Tallis. I heard the Rashab Tallis is significantly wider, why is that? and I heard at times the Rebbe wore a Munkatch Chabad Tallis... What are the differences? How does a person choose? Would the Rebbe change normally?

Answer (score 2):

All Chabad talleisim have a vivid striping pattern, silk corners and headlining, two tzitzis holes on each corner, and no atara.

The Rashab Chabad tallis is so-called because it is a replica of the tallis the Rebbe Rashab personally picked out in Eretz Yisroel.

There is no difference other than the Rashab tallis is slightly larger and has a slightly different striping pattern.

The Munkatch tallis is also just a similar-but-different striping pattern.